# Polynomials in Which No Output Is Contained within Another.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there some polynomial, for example, $f(x)=x^2-3x+2$, such that when you plug in$f(1), f(2), f(3),$ etc, when the output is considered as a string of characters, no output is within another?  Clearly no input can be equal to another.  For example, the polynomial above doesn't work because $f(1)=f(2)$, and $f(5)=12,$ and $f(3)=2$.  The output of 5 contains the output of 3.

Suppose that some output was $65$, and another was $129878565980$.  There would be a violation because $1298785 \mathbf {65}980$ contains $65$. Sorry if this is unclear, I was not sure how to explain it.

Comment: this is definitely unclear. perhaps providing an example of what you are looking for or listing some properties would be helpful

Comment: no, look at $f(1)$ and $f(1+10^n)$ for large $n$

Comment: The polynomial $f(x) = e + \pi x$ works, I think, as long as you only want to plug in integers.

Comment: Sorry.  There was a typo.  I fixed it.  To be clear, I am looking for polynomials with integer coefficients.

Comment: If the two outputs are $605$ and $65$, would this be a violation?

Comment: No.  The string must be continuous.